# How to check if all of value is only text or only integer?

Tags: php

I am trying to prevent sql injection of url by the famous "1 OR 1" technique using get variable to check if id is only string ex:(page.php?id=abc) or integers ex:(page.php?id=12)

So, I used is_string() function to check string and is_numeric for numbers, but all it does is check only the first letter. So, if ( ?id=ab345 ) it will still return true.

So, is there any way of checking if all value is string, and all value is integer only?

This is the link: 
    `<a href="site.com/page.php?id=MyProfile"> My Profile </a>`

this page gets id's and does database queriest
   `if(isset($_GET['id']) {**AND IF ID IS TEXT ONLY**} {Perform code}`
What I am missing is the in between ** **

Comment: your code is wrong: `var_dump(is_numeric('abc123'));` = false

Comment: For id you can use `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];`. Other than numbers nothing else will get through it.

Comment: TextOnly is to make sure that no one can modify the "MyProfile" in `page.php?id=MyProfile` part by making something like `1 OR 1`. So, I need PHP to make sure, whatever is after id is text only

Comment: this is not the best\standard approach for sanitising data for a db

Comment: `1 OR 1` is text only, too. Anyway I added you an answer that should give you some direction, you can filter all $_GET with that, the extension supports that http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php. Apart from that, what you need are prepared statements. That prevent such a kind of SQL injection quite good.

Comment: `$id=$_GET("id");;
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$sql="Update users set lastname='pot' where id=$id"`

Comment: The above code might seem safe, but it can be hacked by making `"1 OR 1=1"`

Comment: As written, use prepared statements, then you do the data-handling at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

`// Request: _GET['id'] = ab345

var_dump(is_numeric($_GET['id'])); // false

var_dump(is_string($_GET['id']));  // true`

`// Request: _GET['id'] = 345

var_dump(is_numeric($_GET['id'])); // true

var_dump(is_string($_GET['id']));  // false`

Comment: Thank for the answer, but can I ask you what var_dump() is supposed to do? I've never used that function before.

Comment: `var_dump` - Dumps information about a variable  
Reference: [http://php.net/var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump)

Answer (score 0):

All these input in PHP by default is *string*. If you need more specific values, you can make use of the filter and validation functions PHP has ([Data Filter<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)), for example see the filters that are available by default: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible answers to your question is;

```
$id = isset(isset($_GET['id'])) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0;    //force to integer, or 0 if not set
```

This will force the value of id to an integer, or to zero if not set in the URL (don't forget the pesky script kiddies who'll manually change the URL to try and break your site!)

But... to be honest... I'm a little concerned that you're even thinking that this will prevent SQL injection attacks. I would highly recommend investing some more time reading further on the subject, and is probably why your question is being voted down.